# Wordpress Theme Option for custom style

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I need a Wordpress Theme Option page with color picker (farbtastic) to change any class or ID of CSS. In my case, I need to change the footer container color (`.footer_container`).

Comment: If you want someone to write code for you, I suggest you try http://wpquestions.com

Comment: I just need help, don't need code from someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the style.css file in your theme folder (/wp-content/themes/yourthemename/style.css). And add your CSS rule there. Themes are rarely fully customizable from the admin area.

Comment: can you mention any theme name which have option to change footer color from admin panel

Comment: If you don't want to mess with the files directly, you can also go to appearance > editor > stylesheet in the backend of your WordPress site.  You'll still need to know some basic CSS to make changes.

Comment: I know CSS and all necessary things for WordPress theme development, and I also know how can we change in CSS through editor, but as mention that I need color picker in theme options page, to change footer color just using hook (add_action)